# How to use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to compute $A^{1000}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, python

$$A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.9 & 0.15 & 0.25 \\
    0.075 & 0.8 & 0.25 \\
    0.025 & 0.05 & 0.5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to use a Python script to compute $A^{1000}$.

I can use numpy's `linalg.eig` function to find my eigenvalues and eigen vectors. Doing so should yield eigenvalues

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1& 0.741 & 0.459 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and eigenvectors
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.891 & 0.737 & -0.276 \\
    0.445 & -0.673 & -0.528 \\
    0.089 & -0.063 & 0.803 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Given this information, I am unsure how to proceed with computing $A^{1000}$

I have tried to use $A^{1000} = PD^{1000}P^{-1}$,  where

$$P=    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.891 & 0.737 & -0.276 \\
    0.445 & -0.673 & -0.528 \\
    0.089 & -0.063 & 0.803 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$P^{-1}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.702 & 0.702 & 0.702 \\
    0.495 & -0.904 & -0.424 \\
    -0.039 & -0.149 & 1.134 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$D=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0.445 & 0.741 & 0 \\
    0 &  & 1.134 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How can you tell the matrix is diagonalizable? and do you mean the columns of the eigenvectors?

Comment: Numpy can probably compute the power directly. Squaring it ten times gets you $A^{1024}$ in only ten multiplications.

Comment: @guacho Perez, I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: @Moo , how can I calculate D^n in Python since I have P and P^-1?

Comment: @Adam Have you tried to use $Ax=x$?

Comment: @callculus, no I have not. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Some more context for this question would be useful in order for you to get an answer that you’re likely to understand. Is this a programming exercise that happens to involve linear algebra, or is this an exercise in a linear algebra course, in which case you’d be expected to know all of the things that are being mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @amd, this is a linear algebra course that wants me to use python to solve the problem as stated above.  You are correct in that some of these methods mentioned in the comments are methods I should be familiar with. I am trying to teach myself linear algebra from an online course and am going through some of the exercises. I am just looking for a simple break down on how to approach this

Comment: As a followup to @GuachoPerez comment, see [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on Wikipedia and [Matrix-exponentiation operator](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix-exponentiation_operator#Python) on Rosetta Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to understand all the steps, so you just need the syntax. Note that this kind of question should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Solution with [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (using the numpy [`matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html) function) and solution with eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg

a = np.matrix([[0.9, 0.15, 0.25], [0.075, 0.8, 0.25], [0.025, 0.05, 0.5]])

np.linalg.matrix_power(a, 1000)

d, p = np.linalg.eig(a)
p * np.diag(d**1000) * np.linalg.inv(p)
```

For both the output is the following matrix (the norm of the difference is close to $1.6\cdot10^{-13}$).

```
matrix([[0.625 , 0.625 , 0.625 ],
        [0.3125, 0.3125, 0.3125],
        [0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625]])
```